# Using AutoLayout to spread 5 subviews evenly across their parent's width in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I'm beyond frustrated with trying to spread 5 subviews within a view while using AutoLayout in Xcode 7. I added five views to a collectionViewController's footer and I would like those views to be spread evenly horizontal-wise while being displayed on devices with differing widths. I was able to find some threads on SO but unfortunately all of them are outdated in Xcode 7 and since I cannot comment due to not having "50 reputation" my only hope is to create my own thread. Would really appreciate the help, going bananas for several hours over this.

Comment: Are you using interface builder or code ?

Comment: Show your code. Where are you struggling? Anything that works with previous versions of Xcode (in this regard) will work pretty much the same way for Xcode 7 also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a very straightforward layout in AutoLayout.

First you need to make sure that all the views have equal widths. In IB you can select them all and use the "add constraints" button in Interface Builder and hit the "Equal Widths" button. In code this is slightly more complex but equally possible.

Second you need to make sure that the leading and trailing edges of each view are "pinned" to each other. Select the first view and (using the "add constraints" button) pin it to the left edge of the super view. Then CTRL-DRAG from the first to the second views and select the "horizontal spacing". Repeat this for each pair of views.

I'd also recommend looking at the www.raywenderlich.com site as they are some very good AutoLayout tutorials there.

Comment: Phew, thank you so much, I actually read one of your past posts on SO describing this solution and earlier it did not work but this time it totally did the trick. Might have been a problem with IB not refreshing itself after making changes. Will check out Wenderlich's tutorials on the subject, thanks.

Comment: @GerwazySokołowski happy to help. Glad it worked for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your adding by code:

```
func constraintsForView(view: UIView, position: Int, superViewWidth: CGFloat) -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
    let views = ["view": view]

    let hDistance: CGFloat = (superViewWidth / 5.0) * CGFloat(position)

    var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    let h = "H:|-\(hDistance)-[view]"
    let v = "V:|[view]|"

    let H_Constraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(h, options: [], metrics: nil, views: views) ?? [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    let V_Constraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(v, options: [], metrics: nil, views: views) ?? [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    constraints.appendContentsOf(H_Constraint)
    constraints.appendContentsOf(V_Constraint)

    constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view.superview, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 0.2, constant: 0))

    return constraints
}
```

This will apply constraints based on their position(1-5)

If your using `Interface Builder` then put the first view in the left and then give it equal widths to superview and change multiplier to 0.2, then add the next view attach left to first view, equal widths again, keep doing same until 5th and just put up/down/left/right

Comment: I'm using IB but thank you for providing that raw code solution, might be very useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can pin equal width constraint. select sub view and parent view set equal width constraint and then edit it's multiplier as per requirement if using IB. Or just give constraint programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

As there was no code attached, I'll just share some of my experience in AutoLayout.

There are two essential points:
1. Make sure you fully understand the mechanism and principles of Autolayout.
2. Practice is absolutely needed, but you need to start with simple cases.

I recommend you get started with xib or storyboard, as they are clear and straightforward. Don't be ambitious at first, try to make two views evenly spread in a parent view at first.

I made a two-step goal for myself during practicing xib.
(1)Add whatever constraint is need, just make sure everything is working without conflicts.
(2)Remove as many constraints as possible, also make sure everything is still working.

After some practice, you'll surely have a better understanding on Apple's auto layout LOGIC, which, I think, is the most important thing.

At last, be patient. Every problem has a solution. It's right there waiting for you to find out.

Comment: Since I was working in IB not sure how I could provide the code, maybe some XML source? Still, thank you for the advice, I actually managed to get this one working with a solution from this thread but I'm totally with you on the understanding AutoLayout logic being crucial which is something I'm not fully familiar with.